# iOS - position view set distance from bottom of screen or keyboard (if it is showing) without subscribing to keyboard notifications

Tags: ios, swift

In Android you can use a `RelativeLayout` and pin a view (such as a button) to the bottom of it using `layout_alignParentBottom`. When the keyboard appears, the view will be right above it.

Is there a way to do this in iOS **without** subscribing to keyboard events and adjusting the view's constraint depending on the keyboard height?

I ask because all the examples I see subscribe to keyboard events. But this is rather buggy from my experience. You have to not only subscribe to keyboard events but app wide events too.

EDIT: For clarification I am asking about doing exactly what I asked. Not adding an `inputAccessoryView`. I would like a view (whether it is a button, image, or anything else) to always stay a set distance from the bottom of the screen. When the keyboard appears, I want that view to then be that same set distance from the top of the keyboard. If the keyboard disappears, the view will move back down to its original position.

Comment: Have you looked into `inputAccessoryView`?

Comment: if you do not wish to subscribe to notifications, I suggest you try **IQKeyboardManager**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no other way. Showing a keyboard is an app-wide event and is so by design. You can get notifications about frame changes and then layout your views accordingly when needed. There are tools that may help you such as mentioned **IQKeyboard** but note this tool may and did get buggy on multiple iOS versions and/or devices so you need to keep updating the library. It is also very hackish but it does work without you needing much work.

From keyboard notifications you can make higher level tools to make things much easier. What I used some time ago was:

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardManagerDidChangeVisibleDelegate: class {
    func keyboardManagerChangedKeyboardVisible(sender: KeyboardManager, visible: Bool)
}
protocol KeyboardManagerWillChangeFrameDelegate: class {
    func keyboardManagerWillChangeKeyboardFrame(sender: KeyboardManager, from startFrame: CGRect, to endFrame: CGRect)
}
protocol KeyboardManagerDidChangeFrameDelegate: class {
    func keyboardManagerDidChangeKeyboardFrame(sender: KeyboardManager, from startFrame: CGRect, to endFrame: CGRect)
}

class KeyboardManager {

    var keyboardVisible: Bool = false
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = CGRect.zero

    var visibilityDelegate: KeyboardManagerDidChangeVisibleDelegate?
    var willChangeFrameDelegate: KeyboardManagerWillChangeFrameDelegate?
    var didChangeFrameDelegate: KeyboardManagerDidChangeFrameDelegate?

    static var sharedInstance: KeyboardManager = {
        let manager = KeyboardManager(isShared: true)
        return manager
    }()

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(isShared: false)

    }

    private init(isShared: Bool) {
        attachNotifications()

        if isShared == false {
            keyboardVisible = KeyboardManager.sharedInstance.keyboardVisible
            keyboardFrame = KeyboardManager.sharedInstance.keyboardFrame
        }
    }

    private func attachNotifications() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardChange), name: .UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }

    @objc private func onKeyboardChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let info = notification.userInfo else {
            return
        }
        guard let value: NSValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
        }
        guard let oldValue: NSValue = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
        }

        let newFrame = value.cgRectValue
        self.keyboardFrame = newFrame

        let oldFrame = oldValue.cgRectValue

        if let durationNumber = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber, let keyboardCurveNumber = info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber {
            let duration = durationNumber.doubleValue
            let keyboardCurve = keyboardCurveNumber.intValue
            let curve: UIViewAnimationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: keyboardCurve) ?? .linear
            let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve.rawValue << 16))

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
                self.willChangeFrameDelegate?.keyboardManagerWillChangeKeyboardFrame(sender: self, from: oldFrame, to: newFrame)
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.didChangeFrameDelegate?.keyboardManagerDidChangeKeyboardFrame(sender: self, from: oldFrame, to: newFrame)
            })
        } else {
            self.willChangeFrameDelegate?.keyboardManagerWillChangeKeyboardFrame(sender: self, from: oldFrame, to: newFrame)
            self.didChangeFrameDelegate?.keyboardManagerDidChangeKeyboardFrame(sender: self, from: oldFrame, to: newFrame)
        }
    }
    @objc private func onKeyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.keyboardVisible = true
        self.visibilityDelegate?.keyboardManagerChangedKeyboardVisible(sender: self, visible: self.keyboardVisible)
    }
    @objc private func onKeyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.keyboardVisible = false
        self.visibilityDelegate?.keyboardManagerChangedKeyboardVisible(sender: self, visible: self.keyboardVisible)
    }

}
```

What I do here is subscribe to will appear delegate `KeyboardManager.sharedInstance.willChangeFrameDelegate = self` in view will appear method of view controller. Then the implementation is simply:

```
extension MyViewController: KeyboardManagerWillChangeFrameDelegate {

    func keyboardManagerWillChangeKeyboardFrame(sender: KeyboardManager, from startFrame: CGRect, to endFrame: CGRect) {
        panelBottomConstraint?.constant = view.bounds.height-max(0, view.convert(endFrame, from: nil).origin.y)
    }

}
```

So still using constraints but since manager is imported only once the amount of code when using it is relatively small. This should already animate your view as well alongside keyboard which is nice.

As for being buggy this procedure has never failed me but in general working with keyboard in iOS is always a pain and is very easy to produce bugs.

Comment: This is very good. One thing that you may run into problems with is if the app goes in the background. This is because you only remove the observers in `deinit`. You need to remove them in something like `applicationWillResignActive` otherwise your constraint will keep moving around if you are in a different app. This is something that has happened to me.

Comment: @Micro Interesting. Well in that case I would not remove the observers but rather check the state on `onKeyboardChange` method and not report to delegates when app is in background. I would then also add another observer on did become active and trigger the delegate calls again with the new frame since it had to be updated.

Comment: *"There is currently no other way"* - sure there is. Make the view the `inputAccessoryView` of the text field or text view. That's it. No other code needed. No libraries, no notifications.

Comment: @rmaddy The question is a bit ambiguous but I believe it is not about what you are posting solution for. I believe “above” is meant as lesser Y position than the keyboard. Like what IQKeyboard does when it pushes the whole screen under the keyboard to bring it up higher. Or am I missing something here and you can achieve this with accessory views as well?

Comment: It's not 100% clear but the first paragraph of the question talks about moving a button and the title says "position a view above keyboard". So my guess is to make the button the `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: @rmaddy “move” the button, not put it there. I assume the button is already on the screen and I believe it would be hard to achieve this animation by dynamically putting it on accessory view while keyboard is being shown. But you might want to ask OP what he meant...